# RabbitMq is not consuming the message when running the script through nohup

Tags: python, linux, rabbitmq, nohup

I have multiple rabbitmq queue which recieve the message. I recently add 2 more queue in my file but when i run that reciever script through nohup, it is not able to consume the message although in background script is running. when i run the same script by  `python script.py` It is working fine. My all previous rabbitmq reciever queue is working fine with nohup. My nohup command to run
the script is `nohup python  script.py >> script-rabbit-reciever-app.log 2>&1 &`. Is there any limitation of how many process we can run through nohup?

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on `nohup` which is a single command (in this case is just is `python`).  You are limited in the number of instances in `nohup` which is the same as any other process in linux.  You can see the process limit for a user in most common shells with `ulimit -u`